# Implementing a multi-threaded web crawler with Java's ReadWriteLocks

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to implement a multi-threaded web crawler using ReadWriteLocks.
I have a Callable calling an API to get page URLs and crawl them when they are not present in the Seen URLs Set.

From the ExecutorService I am using three threads to do the crawl.

The problem is - different threads are reading the same URL twice. How can I prevent different threads from reading a visited URL?

```
package Threads;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;

public class WebCrawler {

     static HashSet<String> seenURL = new HashSet<>();
     List<String> resultVisitedUrls = new ArrayList<>();
     ReadWriteLock lock_http_request = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
     Lock readLock_http_request = lock_http_request.readLock();
     Lock writeLock_http_request = lock_http_request.writeLock();


    public  boolean contains(String url){
        readLock_http_request.lock();
        try {
            if(!seenURL.contains(url)){
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }finally {
            readLock_http_request.unlock();
        }
    }
    public void addUrlToSeenURLSet(String url){

        writeLock_http_request.lock();
        try{
            seenURL.add(url);

        }finally {
            writeLock_http_request.unlock();
        }
    }

    public List<String> getResultVisitedUrls() {
        return resultVisitedUrls;
    }


    public void crawl(String startUrl, HtmlParser htmlParser, WebCrawler crawler) throws Exception {


        if (!crawler.contains(startUrl)) {
            try {
                crawler.addUrlToSeenURLSet(startUrl);
                List<String> subUrls = htmlParser.getUrls(startUrl);

                resultVisitedUrls.add(startUrl + "  Done by thread - " + Thread.currentThread());

                for (String subUrl : subUrls) {
                    crawl(subUrl, htmlParser, crawler); 
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception("Something went wrong. Method - crawl : " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Crawl implements Callable<List<String>> {
            String startUrl;
            WebCrawler webCrawler;

            public Crawl(String startUrl, WebCrawler webCrawler){
                this.startUrl = startUrl;
                this.webCrawler = webCrawler;
            }

            public List<String> call() {
                HtmlParser htmlParser = new RetrieveURLs();
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    webCrawler.crawl(startUrl, htmlParser, webCrawler);
                    result =  webCrawler.getResultVisitedUrls();
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.err.println("Some exception occurred in run() - " + ex.getMessage());
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        try{
            WebCrawler webCrawler = new WebCrawler();
            WebCrawler webCrawler1 = new WebCrawler();

            Future<List<String>> future_1 = service.submit(new Crawl("http://localhost:3001/getUrls/google.com", webCrawler));
            Future<List<String>> future_2 = service.submit(new Crawl("http://localhost:3001/getUrls/google.com", webCrawler1));
            Future<List<String>> future_3 = service.submit(new Crawl("http://localhost:3001/getUrls/google.com", webCrawler1));

            List<String> result_1 = future_1.get();
            List<String> result_2 = future_2.get();
            List<String> result_3 = future_3.get();

            result_1.addAll(result_2);
            result_2.addAll(result_3);
            //Assert.assertEquals(6, result_1.size());
            System.out.println(result_1.size());
            for(String str : result_1){
                System.out.println(str );
            }

        }catch(ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex){

        }finally {
            service.shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Essentially, you have a "check then act" problem. Between `!cralwer.contains(startUrl)` and `crawler.addUrlToSceenURLSet(startUrl)` you release the lock, allowing two threads to see `false` returned by the `contains` call.

Answer (score 2):

Your fault lies with fact that 2 threads can call `contains(url)` with same value and both get false, so they both then enter the code block with `crawler.addUrlToSeenURLSet(startUrl)`. The `seenURL.add(url)` returns a status code which you've ignored - this tells you which thread succeeded.

Rather than using a pair of locks just use a concurrent set which is backed by `ConcurrentHashMap` and thread-safe.

```
private static final Set<String> seenURLs = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
```

When you use this set you only need to call `add` as that returns `true` on first call and `false` if the set already contains the same `startUrl` value that another thread is working on:

```
if(seenURLs.add(startUrl)) {
   ... crawl 
}
```

Alternatively if you wish to use a lock you should change `addUrlToSeenURLSet` to `return seenURL.add(url);` to confirm which thread succeeds, and then you only need this test before running the crawl:

```
if(addUrlToSeenURLSet(startUrl)) {
   ... crawl 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I put `!` into those if statements, add returns true for the thread that is successful. Fixed

Comment: This answer still holds. Two threads can both run `if (!crawler.contains(startUrl)) {` *simultaneously*, and both get the same `true` result, and so both then execute the following block, which adds the URL to `seenURL` and continues crawling. The solution is to arrange your locks so that checking and adding is a single atomic operation, or use a data structure that inherently behaves appropriately, such as the `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` suggested in this answer.